# Use a loop to run many regressions at once

Tags: r, loops

I have a data set with 147 columns, each with 7 rows. I want to run a separate regression analysis using each column.

```
fit = nls(DD$X1, ~ (1/(1+k*xValues)),start=list(k=k))
```

Explanation:

`DD` is the dataset: it's a data frame) The levels are "X1," "X2", etc.

```
xValues = c(1,2,7,14,30,180,720)
```

`k` is the parameter I'm trying to determine)

But I want to do it in a loop, e.g. next to do it for DD$2, ... all the way to DD$147. 
Along the way I'd like to store the values of fit.

I'm new to r: could someone suggest how to do this? Many thanks.

Comment: Either write a loop, assigning the results each time thru to a `list` variable `fit[[j]]<-nls(DD[[j]]....)` or do the same but using `?sapply` .  If you can't write a `for` loop then please read the `R-intro` PDF document available at all CRAN mirrors.

Comment: You could also use `data.table` for this. Something like `library(data.table) ;  Res <- setDT(DD)[, list(lapply(.SD, function(x) nls(x ~ (1/(1+k*xValues)), start=list(k=k))))]` will store your results, and in order to view them, do `Res[, lapply(V1, print)]`

Answer (score 0):

I am using BodyFat dataset here. You have to replace dataset file name and also assign proper column to response and explanatory variables.

```
formu <-function(a,lis)
{
 k=""
 k= paste(a,'~',sep="")
 h=do.call("paste", c(lis, sep = "+"))
 formula1= paste(k,h,sep="")
 return(formula1) 
}

results=list()
dat = read.table("BodyFatPercentage.txt",header=TRUE)
g=names(dat)
target=names(dat)[2:2]
print(target)
expla=names(dat)[3:16]
for(i in 1:length(expla))
{
 formula1=formu(target,list(expla[i]))
 model1=lm(formula1,dat)
 print(model1)
 results[i] = model1
}
print results
```