# R regressions in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have an excel files with 12 columns. I need to regress six of these on one column (i.e. six univariate linear regressions.) I would like to write a loop which does the regressions, and then store all the summary statistics (`intercept`, `beta`, `R^2`, `standard deviations`, `statistical significance`) in a matrix and print all of them at once.
I can run the regressions separately if need be but I am trying to do it more efficiently. I looked at this [How to Loop/Repeat a Linear Regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952653/how-to-loop-repeat-a-linear-regression-in-r) but I couldn't figure it out.

I tried writing the following loop:

```
for(i in [,7]:[,12]) {
  lmoutput<-lm(i~rm)
  print(lmoutput)
  }
```

but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
#for(i in [,7]:[,12]) {
#Error: unexpected '[' in "for(i in ["
#  lmoutput<-lm(i~rm)
#Error in model.frame.default(formula = i ~ rm, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
#  variable lengths differ (found for 'rm')
#  print(lmoutput)
#Error in print(lmoutput) : object 'lmoutput' not found
#}
#Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Columns 7-12 are the ones I have to regress on column 2, which I named `rm`.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The `plyr` package and `ddply()` can do what you need to do.  [Here's a question that is very similar to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029922/linear-regression-and-storing-results-in-data-frame/28030653#28030653).